# Is it possible to know the location from which the internet is used

Tags: programming-languages

I am developing a website and i need to know learn the location of visiting user(PC and mobile), i.e the user city.

Also tell me preferable technology and framework for developing a fast dynamic website like Digg. Actually, as far as my understanding goes, the asp.net websites are a bit slower than PHP/Javascript. May be i am wrong, but visiting Microsoft's website, seem to give this impression.

Thanks All !!

Comment: It would break user security if you know their location.

Comment: There are plenty of geo location services and databases availible for exactly what you're attempting to do.  That's the key term 'geolocation' -- if you use this term for your research, you are bound to find many sources to assist you in this kind of functionality.

Comment: @Aleksandar : If one gets the permission to do so from user then this won't be an issue of privacy, right or will it still be ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HTML 5's geoLocation API, or use the user's IP address and try to find it's location - Google offers such a service

Comment: i have marked this as answer but still got some confusion :-) , first of all, does geolocation uses GPS and second if someone logs from mobile, can we still attain the IP address for identifying location

Comment: Buddy i checked various website for my location. But none of them named correct city. I don't think IP address helps to find the correct location.